# how to separate $n and numbers in std::regex_replace?

Tags: c++, regex, fmt, stdformat

I have such a regex pattern:

```cpp
string text = "ekwfwierflwi..DATE..wdwedwd"
const string pattern = "([\s\S]*)(DATE)([\s\S]*)";
```

Then I hope to replace date to a number sequence:

```cpp
const string format = fmt::format("$1{}$3", "2024-04.05 12:00:00");
std::regex_replace(text, pattern, format);
```

But it will become `$12024-04.05...`.
I tried `${1}`, but it has no effect.

May be search only part of the string at two or three times and concat them, or replace it with another value and replace it back.

Any other way directly?

I wonder if there is a concise way

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
std::regex_replace(text, "DATE", fmt::format("{}", "2024-04.05 12:00:00"))
```

(assuming you have a dynamic date you want to format and not just a simple text string...)

Comment: Oh, I'm too fool. I thought since it only match the part of `DATE`, it won't keep other part. Thank you for your correction